# Wrong pass prop in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context

I have simple **Reactjs** app that includes the `Card` and `Modal` components. every `Card` must have a `Modal` that when clicking on "Show More" button, open it.

Modal should only show the title on its Card and my problem is passed props to Modal, just send the `title` of the last `Card` And not about itself!

In summary, the prop of `title` received properly in Card component but Card component can't pass `title` to Modal correctly.

Here is my app in CodeSandBox: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/card-and-modal-9fzj5)

*Card Components:*

```
const Card = props => {
  const { children, title } = props;
  const { isShowModal, setIsShowModal } = useContext(MainContext);

  const showModalHandler = () => {
    setIsShowModal(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-header">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
      </div>

      <div className="card-content">{children}</div>
      <div className="card-footer">
        <button onClick={showModalHandler}>Show More</button>
      </div>

      {isShowModal && <Modal title={title} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```

*Modal Component:*

```
const Modal = props => {
  const { setIsShowModal } = useContext(MainContext);

  const closeModalHandler = () => {
    setIsShowModal(false);
  };

  const { title } = props;

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <h2>Modal: {title}</h2>
      <p>
        You cliked on <b>{title}</b> Card
      </p>
      <hr />
      <button onClick={closeModalHandler}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Note:** I use Context for control open/close modal in `isShowModal` state and maybe that's the problem?

Comment: The actual problem is not very clear from your description

Comment: @William Please see the demo. `title` not pass correctly to modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you thought the problem seems to be the `useContext` that you are using. So I made a couple of changes to the code, most importantly using `useState`. I recommend you read the documentation about `useContext` and when to use it. Here is the updated code:

`Card.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "./Modal";
import "./Card.scss";

const Card = props => {
  const { children, title } = props;
  const [ isShowModal, setIsShowModal ] = useState(false);


  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-header">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
      </div>

      <div className="card-content">{children}</div>
      <div className="card-footer">
        <button onClick={() => setIsShowModal(true)}>Show More</button>
      </div>

      {isShowModal && <Modal setIsShowModal={setIsShowModal} title={title} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

`Modal.js`

```
import React from "react";
import "./Modal.scss";

const Modal = props => {

  const { title } = props;

  return (
    <div className="modal">
      <h2>Modal: {title}</h2>
      <p>
        You cliked on <b>{title}</b> Card
      </p>
      <hr />
      <button onClick={() => props.setIsShowModal(false)}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

As you can see, `Modal.js` component doesn't have to be a stateful component. You can pass as a prop the `setIsShowModal` function from `Card.js` component. That way you can make the modal a reusable component.